# Help with double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove if this integral exist (and some others) but i would like to know if there is a condition to say if the integral exist (for example in this case) that would help me solve this kind of exercises

$$\int\int_{x^2+y^2\leq 1} \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)} dx\,dy$$

Comment: Try using a variable change, let $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = rsin(\theta)$ and calculate the value of the integral

Comment: I would consider the limit $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\iint_{\epsilon\le x^2+y^2\le1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the only working method to decide whether an integral converges is to use estimates. If you can bound the (positive) integrand function from above by an integrable function, you are done. 
If you can estimate it from below by a non-integrable (positive) function, again you are done.

However, this approach is often useless in exercises, where some tricky approach must be used. In you example, the quickest approach is by switching to polar coordinates, although you can also use the Fubini-Tonelli theorem and partial integration. As my instructor told me, with double integrals you need to get your hands dirty, and compute as far as you can. You try to reduce your integral to the integral in 1D, and then you decide more easily if it converges.